# Custom Field to Page Layout via Partner or Metadata API

Tags: api

Can I add Custom field to Page Layout via Partner or Metadata API ?
Any Example would be great

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible through the [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/). The Metadata API is actually what drives all deployments. You are actually looking for the [`Layout`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_layouts.htm) which:

> Represents the metadata associated with a page layout.

Essentially, when doing a pull on your page layout's metadata, you will get something like below returned as XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Layout xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <customConsoleComponents>
    <primaryTabComponents>
       <container>
           <region>left</region>
          <style>Stack</style>
          <unit>Pixel</unit>
          <width>101</width>
          <sidebarComponent>
                <width>60</width>
                <page>simplepage1</page>
                <unit>Percentage</unit>
          </sidebarComponent>
          <sidebarComponent>
                <width>40</width>
                <page>Hello_World</page>
                <unit>Percentage</unit>
          </sidebarComponent>
       </container>
    </primaryTabComponents>
    <subtabComponents>
       <component>
          <location>top</location>
          <visualforcePage>ConsoleComponentPage2</visualforcePage>
          <height>200</height>
       </component>
    </subtabComponents>
   </customConsoleComponents>
    <customButtons>ButtonLink</customButtons>
    <layoutSections>
        <editHeading>true</editHeading>
        <label>Information</label>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Required</behavior>
                <field>Name</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <height>180</height>
                <scontrol>LayoutSControl</scontrol>
                <showLabel>true</showLabel>
                <showScrollbars>true</showScrollbars>
                <width>50%</width>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <reportChartComponent>
                   <contextFilterableField>CUST_ID</contextFilterableField>
                   <includeContext>true</includeContext>
                   <reportName>Open_Accounts_by_Cases</reportName>
                   <showTitle>false</showTitle>
                   <size>LARGE</size>
                <reportChartComponent>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                <field>OwnerId</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                <field>CurrencyIsoCode</field>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <style>TwoColumnsTopToBottom</style>
    </layoutSections>
    <layoutSections>
        <editHeading>true</editHeading>
        <label>System Information</label>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>CreatedById</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>Alpha1__c</field>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>LastModifiedById</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                <field>TextArea__c</field>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <style>TwoColumnsTopToBottom</style>
    </layoutSections>
    <layoutSections>
        <customLabel>true</customLabel>
        <detailHeading>true</detailHeading>
        <label>Custom Links</label>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems>
                <customLink>CustomWebLink</customLink>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <style>CustomLinks</style>
    </layoutSections>
    <relatedContent>
        <relatedContentItems>
            <layoutItem>
                <component>sfa:socialPanel</component>
            </layoutItem>
        <relatedContentItems>
    </relatedContent>
    <miniLayoutFields>Name</miniLayoutFields>
    <miniLayoutFields>OwnerId</miniLayoutFields>
    <miniLayoutFields>CurrencyIsoCode</miniLayoutFields>
    <miniLayoutFields>Alpha1__c</miniLayoutFields>
    <miniLayoutFields>TextArea__c</miniLayoutFields>
    <miniRelatedLists>
        <relatedList>RelatedNoteList</relatedList>
    </miniRelatedLists>
    <relatedLists>
        <fields>StepStatus</fields>
        <fields>CreatedDate</fields>
        <fields>OriginalActor</fields>
        <fields>Actor</fields>
        <fields>Comments</fields>
        <fields>Actor.Alias</fields>
        <fields>OriginalActor.Alias</fields>
        <relatedList>RelatedProcessHistoryList</relatedList>
    </relatedLists>
    <relatedLists>
        <relatedList>RelatedNoteList</relatedList>
    </relatedLists>
</Layout>
```

You will have to go through it and play with it a bit, but you should definitely be able to edit how the fields are laid out by modifying that XML and using the [Force.com Ant Migration Tool](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Sorry for late response but I am not able to do that via Layout object. Can you provide some code example ?